# Back pressed disable after login or registration

Tags: android

So I have an app where I need to do a login and a registration. Both make a call to the API and the response returns a unique token. I plan to store this token in Shared Preferences and clear it when logout. My question is how to treat the back pressed after login or register? Once the user is logged in if he presses the back button I don't want to come back to the login/registration screen.

Comment: If login success `finish()` Login/RegisterActivity.

Comment: finish() or onBackPressed() both can work as expected for you

Answer (score 0):

Once Login or Registration is successful use 
`finish()` to destroy the Login or Registration activity

Answer (score 0):

as my friends say, after a successful login, you should to finish this activity by calling finish() method, and then start new activity, or start new activity and then finish login activity, no different,
just remember to finish login activity by calling `finish();`

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class to store that kind of session info.
Storing it in `SharedPreferences` can lead you to that token not being deleted if the user (or the OS itself) kills the application process.

Anyway, if you want to do it that way, you only have to override `onBackPressed` method of your `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Here you can do whatever you want. Leave it blank if you
    // want not to do anything, or show a Logout popup... whatever you need
    // If you want to close all activities, call finishAffinity()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second activity (the one you go to after login or registration) override the `onBackPressed` method and implement your own logic inside it. You could choose to do nothing when back is pressed, **or** maybe exit the app alltogether. Is is up to you.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
         // Leave empty if you want nothing to happen, or do something else if you wish

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start your next activity from login or register screen with intent flags which will clear activity stack, and now when user press back any activity before your current activity will not be displayed. You can read more about intent flags here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent

```
private void startActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `finish()` to destroy activity. But finish only remove current activity from back stack in which it is called.
So there is a case like first log in screen appear and from login user goes to register activity after successful registration if you call finish it will remove registration activity from back stack but login activity remain in back stack and when you press back you will get back to log in screen so **call `finishAffinity()` to remove all previous activity on successful login or registration.**

Note: If you block user to back button that is not good practice, in this way user can't get back to home screen by pressing back button.